# position:absolute and scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable `div` composed of rows. Each row has inside an invisible `span` which becomes visible when you click the row. The span, when opened, is (correctly) at the same height of the row.

However, if I scroll the main container, since the spans are in fixed position, they wont be at the same height of the row anymore. Since this issue is really difficult to explain, [here's the JSFiddle I've prepared](http://jsfiddle.net/LM32h/5/). Try to click a row without scrolling. Reload the page and try it again but just after scrolling to div to the bottom.

`position:absolute` is the only thing I can do to let the span "pop up" of the row but, at the same time, is the thing which is screwing the positioning relative to the row. `position:relative` should work, but the span are considerably bigger than the rows and the latters are using `overflow:hidden`.

Please note that the example is a quick copy of a much complex structure which is created with data binding libraries: I cannot change this structure and jQuery is not even an option. Ideally, I need to solve this problem just with CSS but I have no idea how: is there any alternative to `position:fixed` which works if I scroll the div?

Comment: Is giving the span position:relative; out of the option? It seems to give the functionality you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/LM32h/6/

Comment: unfortunately I can't - I'm updating both the question and the fiddle to show why. Rows must use overflow:hidden to prevent content goind out and span are biggers than rows. Thanks for your help btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `top` with JS in your click event.

```
$('.row').click(function () {
    var pos = $(this).position().top;
    $(this).find('span').css({
        "display": "block",
        "top":pos
    });
});
```

May want to add/subtract from `pos`, depending on exact placement needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/LM32h/8/